# Solr multivalued field get index

Tags: solr

I have two multivalued solr fields. Is it possible to get the index of one value in one field and use that index to get the value of another field.

For example:
Field1: [A,B,C]
Field2:[2010,2011,2012]

I want to know what letter is in 2012.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you post an example document or two. You can query for field2:2012 that will return this document which will have field1 with all A,B,C letters as values .

Comment: {
        "id": "0",
        "Tags": [
          "boots",
          "big",
          "shoes"
        ],
        "extrac_dates": [
          "2013-09-03T17:33:18.7Z",
          "2013-09-02T17:33:18.7Z",
          "2013-09-01T17:33:18.7Z"
        ],
        "_version_": 1454343394585215000,
        "timestamp": "2013-12-13T21:25:42.65Z"
      }

Comment: so if i query by 2013-09-03, how to get "boots" in Tags...

Comment: Please post data definition for Tags from your schema.xml file.

Comment: It first of all should be multivalued, indexed,stored. it might be string or other text format. This is just a test data. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

yes, if you have those fields stored, then, you are guaranteed its values will be returned in the same order they were inserted. So you can retrieve both fields, look at what position is 2012 in Field2, then look at that position in Field1.

See [here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/quot-order-quot-question-on-solr-multi-value-field-td4027695.html) for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply. but what if I want to retrieve the field by query in solr, but retrieve both fields and find it myself? BTW, I also posted an example data as the comment above.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean, can you elaborate/rephrase?